# How to reduce oracle query response time

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query is running fine except the response time,it will take 4 sec to fetch the records, I need to know the best practicing tips to write the same, so query execution time will be improve.

```
SELECT name,loc_id,tot_emp,net_salary,gross_earn,gross_deduct,case WHEN YEAR_MONTH IS NOT NULL THEN YEAR_MONTH ELSE 'NA' END AS Month
FROM
--SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  
r.NAME, 
'000' loc_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT ess.employee_id) tot_emp,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.net_salary else 0 end) net_salary,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_earning else 0 end) gross_earn,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_deduction else 0 end) gross_deduct,
MAX(ess.YEAR_MONTH)YEAR_MONTH 
FROM Region r
JOIN EMPLOYEE e
ON r.REGION_ID=e.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_SALARY_SUMMARY ess
ON ess.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMP_ID
WHERE e.CIRCLE_ID IS NULL 
group by r.NAME, '000'
UNION 
SELECT 
c.name,
c.circle_id loc_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT ess.employee_id) tot_emp,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.net_salary else 0 end) net_salary,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_earning else 0 end) gross_earn,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_deduction else 0 end) gross_deduct,
MAX(ess.YEAR_MONTH)YEAR_MONTH
FROM circle c
JOIN EMPLOYEE e
ON c.CIRCLE_ID=e.CIRCLE_ID
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_SALARY_SUMMARY ess
ON ess.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMP_ID 
group by c.name, c.circle_id
)mtybl
ORDER BY loc_id;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: already tried, but still take 4 sec

Comment: Is it the first or second select that is too slow? Have you checked the explain output?

Comment: second select is more expensive First SELECT didn't take long, but second SELECT takes 2-3 sec

Comment: Do you have an index on EMPLOYEE.CIRCLE_ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace union with joins, I have made some changes on above query test it with your data. I have used left joins by taking reference from your query but try to use inner joins for better performance.

```
SELECT name,loc_id,tot_emp,net_salary,gross_earn,gross_deduct,YEAR_MONTH
--SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT  
r.NAME, 
CASE WHEN C.CIRCLE_ID IS NULL THEN '000' ELSE c.circle_id END loc_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT ess.employee_id) tot_emp,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.net_salary else 0 end) net_salary,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_earning else 0 end) gross_earn,
SUM(CASE WHEN ess.employee_id IS NOT NULL  Then ess.gross_deduction else 0 end) gross_deduct,
CASE WHEN MAX(ess.YEAR_MONTH) IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE MAX(ess.YEAR_MONTH) END YEAR_MONTH
FROM EMPLOYEE e Region 
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SALARY_SUMMARY ess
ON ess.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMP_ID
LEFT JOIN Region r
ON r.REGION_ID=e.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN circle c 
ON c.CIRCLE_ID = e.CIRCLE_ID
group by r.NAME, '000', c.circle_id
)mtybl
ORDER BY loc_id;
```

Comment: If you have a circle_id then you want to return the circle's name not the region's name.